# Inconsistency in interpreting python float in pytorch - why?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

In pytorch, the default dtype of python `float` in `torch.Tensor` creation is `torch.float32`:

```
a = torch.tensor([1.])
a.dtype
>>> torch.float32
```

But when dtype is explicitly given as `float`, or in `torch.Tensor.to` method, python `float` is casted as `torch.float64`:

```
a = torch.tensor([1.], dtype=float)
a.dtype
>>> torch.float64

a = torch.tensor([1.]).to(float)
a.dtype
>>> torch.float64
```

Q. What kind of reasonings behind this inconsistency? I naturally assume that there must be some benefit/avoidance of nasty bugs in bearing with this mismatch in default dtype for python `float` on the level of such basic tensor operations.

---

Edit. I just wonder why pytorch team choose `torch.tensor(x)` different from `torch.tensor(x).to(float)` when `x` consists of `float`s.

Comment: Is `randn` in the second example a typo?  Should that be `rand` like in the first example?

Comment: @CryptoFool Both are accepted by pytorch, but in any case my code blocks were misleading as my question has little to do with internals of `rand`(or `randn`) function. I just modified the code to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric):

> Floating point numbers are usually implemented using `double` in C

`double` in C is normally a 64-bit number (double-precision, as opposed to the single-precision 32-bit `float` type), and it's also known as `float64`. So, what we call `float` in plain Python is usually a 64-bit float, or `torch.float64`.

PyTorch itself, however, uses `float32` by default. AFAIK, this is done to save memory: you'll likely be training models with quite a lot of parameters, and using 32-bit floats will take two times less memory than Python's 64-bit `float`.

Comment: Then why they choose `torch.float64` when `tensor.to(float)` is called? Isn't the logic of memory saving apply equally well to `.to(float)` method? I just wonder why `torch.tensor(x)` should be different to `torch.tensor(x).to(float)` if `x` consists of `float`s.

Comment: The `float` in `tensor.to(float)` is Python's `float` type. Python's `float` type is actually a 64-bit float (also known as `double` in C). Thus, it would make sense for `.to(float)` to mean `.to(torch.float64)`. I couldn't find this explicitly stated in the documentation, though - it specifies types using `torch.float32` or `torch.float64`.

Comment: Oh I got your point; when `float` is given explicitly as `dtype` then pytorch follows python's type casting rule, otherwise naive `float` entries in a list would follow pytorch default, which is `float32` to save memory. Still their choice is fairly unintuitive I think.